# Kafka Tool: error connecting to cluster failed to create new kafkaAdminClient

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using Kafka tool everything was fine then we have enabled SSL to Kafka.
I have given proper jks file location and password in Kafka tool still it's not connecting.

[image: kafka tool error]

Comment: I have the same problem here